# the syntax for getting an input line to repeat itself if there is no input

Tags: python

I am a new programmer and I am trying to make an interactive list and I forgot the line that is needed for it

```
 first=input("did you take out the trash?  : ")
if first==("yes"):
    print("that's good")
while len(first)==0:
```

it is the last line that is bugging me and I don't even know how to format the question on google.Thank you for reading

Comment: There is always input (unless the user aborts the program or something like that). It just might be an empty string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I am a new programmer... Thank you for reading" Please do not include things like this. It does not change the answer, does not change our responsibility to explain things clearly (we always have that responsibility, but only if the question meets the necessary standards to be answered) and it [makes the question worse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721).